# is there any way to resize a terminal with ncurses?

Tags: ruby, terminal, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to build a program using curses and ruby. There is a resizeterm function that changes the dimensions of the curses window [resizeterm](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-resizeterm). But it does not actually resize my mac terminal window (gui), only the virtual one within.

Is there a way to programatically change the window size from a curses program?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, as I've never seen anything adjust the size of a Terminal window. It is possible with something like `xterm` using X specific APIs.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Resizing the application window sounds like something the is very dependent on the desktop environment instead of the terminal environment. I would go looking for a way to talk to the desktop environment.

Comment: Even if it was possible I think many would find it annoying. Perhaps printing a message like "please enlarge your terminal window" would be more user friendly anyway.